# debugging google earth pluggin with chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am developing a web application with google earth pluggin, on windows 7.
I have notices that when I am printing earth objects to the chrome console (for deguggin and code checks)
the objects are empty ( looks like "Object {} "). I couldn't find the reason after much googling.. Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Update: Here is the code I am running. I need help, it is impossible working without debugging..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map3d" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
    <!--nothing inside this -->
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
        var ge;

        function init() {
            google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
        };

        function initCB(instance) {
            ge = instance;
            ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(ge, null, 4));
            console.log('0%', ge);
            console.log(ge.parseKml);
        };

        function failureCB(errorCode) {
            throw ("Failed to load earth plugin. Error code = " + errorCode);
        };

        google.load("earth", "1", { "other_params": "sensor={false}" });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everithing works, and I can see the map, but the result in the console:

```
{}
0% Object {}
function parseKml() { [native code] }
```

Comment: If console returns you `"Object {}"` than probably *it is* an object. It just might be it's returned as *"String"* (so you cannot explore it) *or* it just might be really an *Empty* Object... I don't think anyone could be able to help you on that matter unless you show / explain something more.

Comment: even if i create a hardcoded placemark and write it to the console it looks empty, I thought someone might have incountered that problem.

Comment: p.s. the object code is `%O` not `0%` (it is an `O` for object, not a zero `0`) - also it is percent first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either try to convert the object to JSON first. e.g.

`console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));`

Or else use `%O` to force the format of the value as an expandable JavaScript object. e.g.

`console.log('%O', obj);`

Failing that output values rather than objects. e.g.

`console.log(ge.getPluginVersion());` not `console.log(ge);`

EDIT

Based on your code that is what you would expect to see. You should log the values you are interested in as I mentioned in the last example. e.g.

`console.log(ge.getPluginVersion());` not `console.log(ge);`

You can also test to see what an API object is at runtime by calling `getType`. e.g.

`console.log(ge.getType());`  // GEPlugin

You can also test to see if an API object has a property/method at runtime using `in`. e.g.

`console.log('createPlacemark' in ge)`  // true

To help you can always use the [Google Earth API Reference](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/) if you want to know what properties and methods an API object has, or you could even open the object in something like visual studios object browser.

Comment: I was hopeful, but it doesn't work. Even if I try to print the basic ge object, it comeout empty. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Hmm both work for me. Can you post a clear example of what you are trying to do in code?

Comment: Posted my code, please if you can take a look. Thank you!

Comment: Got it buy it is disappointing. It is easier when you can see the properties and methods of the object directly in the console, or watch. Thanks anyway!

Comment: True, but you can always call the `getType()` method on an object to at least know what API type it is. If all you want all the methods/properties of the GEPlugin object they are here: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin.  Also you can test a method/property exists on an Api object at runtime using `in` e.g. `if('createPlacemark' in ge) { //... }` etc. I have re-edited my answer to give examples of this.